# Rails - creating multiple objects from one form

Tags: ruby-on-rails, nested-forms, form-for

I have a form that when filled out will update the attributes for one or many "treatment adaptation" objects. I would like to take three attributes from each one of these objects, and use those to create a "task" object every time the form is filled out and saved - the hidden field (:name), :adaptation_details (would become :content in task object) and :researcher/agency_leader/:direct_provider which would become :assigned_to on the task. I'm getting a undefined method `merge' for :content:Symbol error:

Form:

```
= form_tag update_individual_treatment_adaptations_path, :method => "put", :id => "myAdaptationsForm" do |f|    
- for treatment_adaptations in @current_agency.treatment_adaptations.order('created_at ASC')
    =fields_for "treatment_adaptations[]", treatment_adaptations do |f|
        - if treatment_adaptations.not_doing_adaptation != 'true'
            %tr
                %td
                    = f.hidden_field :name, :value => treatment_adaptations.name
                %td
                    = f.text_area :adaptation_details, :content, :rows => 10
                %td
                    = f.check_box :treatment_developer, :assigned_to
                    Treatment Developer
                    %br     
                    = f.check_box :researcher, :assigned_to
                    Researcher
                    %br     
                    = f.check_box :agency_leader, :assigned_to
                    Agency Leader
                    %br     
                    = f.check_box :supervisor, :assigned_to
                    Supervisor
                    %br 
                    = f.check_box :direct_provider, :assigned_to
                    Direct Supervisor
                    %br 
                    = f.check_box :implementation_team, :assigned_to
                    Direct Supervisor
                    %br 
                    %br
                    Other:
                    %br
                    = f.text_area :other_implementer, :assigned_to
= submit_tag 'Save', class: 'btn btn-primary'
```

Controller:

```
def update_individual
    @task = @current_agency.tasks.build(treatment_adaptations_params[:task])

    @treatment_adaptations = TreatmentAdaptation.update(params[:treatment_adaptations].except(:task).keys, params[:treatment_adaptations].except(:task).values).reject { |p| p.errors.empty? }
    if @treatment_adaptations.empty?
        set_flash "adaptations updated"
        redirect_to :back
    else
        set_flash "adaptations could not be updated", :error
        redirect_to :back
    end
end


private

    def treatment_adaptations_params
        params.require( :treatment_adaptation ).permit( :org_level, :provider_factors, :client_chars, 
        :system_level, :other_reasons, :concerns, :other_concerns, :proceed_with_plan, :seek_further_consultation,
        :address_concern, :address_concern_text, :adaptation_details, :treatment_developer, :researcher, :agency_leader,
        :supervisor, :direct_provider, :implementation_team, :other_implementer, task: [:name, :content, :assigned_to])
    end
```

Comment: waow, lot of code here. May be the first thing to do is to isolate your problem by reducing the number of lines of code involved, this will help us!

Comment: Good suggestion. I cleaned up the code to contain only the relevant lines.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My solution was to use an after_save callback on the treatment_adaptation model to create tasks that would pull over the necessary treatment_adaptation attributes.